# How to display Multidimensional Associative Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to display an array like this?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [dogs] => Array ( 
            [Cordillera Autonomous Region (CAR)] => Array ( 
                [link] => /search/veterinarians/?vet&provid=1&animal=ZG9ncw==&keyword=Abra&keysearch=QWJyYQ==&c 
                [city] => Abra 
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: how to display.... where?

Comment: echo using foreach.

Comment: Looks like the output of `var_dump()` ... to get it showing properly in a browser you'll want to enclose it in <pre></pre> tags

Comment: explain your question you want to display or create

Comment: I already have the array and I just want to echo all the values of link & city

Comment: Ok I get it, another question how could I remove index array or parent key of the array, I mean the zero

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're most probably looking for an output similar to this:

```
<?php

foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $category) {
        foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
            echo $key . ' : <a href="' $value['link'] . '">' . $value['city'] '</a>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Completely up to you how you actually output the data, but the structure of it lends itself to an output similar to this. You can nest `foreach` loops very easily in PHP.